# Evaluating stationary points with null Hessian determinant

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Given the function
$f(x,y)=x^2y^3$
I'm asked to evaluate all the stationary point.

**My work:**
I started calculating the derivatives: $f_x=2xy^3$ and $f_y=3x^2y^2$ then I looked for the point such that $(f_x,f_y)=(0,0)$.
Since I got the points on the axes I mean that the stationary point are kinda like $(0,y),(x,0)$ I wrote the Hessian.
$$\left(\begin{matrix} 
2y^3& 6xy^2\\
6xy^2& 6x^2y\\
\end{matrix}\right)
$$
And is determinant results to be $12x^2y^4-36x^2y^4=-24x^2y^4$ so that the determinant in $(0,0)$ is equal to $0$.

Now I tried to check the functions on different curves to evaluate the point or better is increment:$\Delta f=f(x,y)-f(x,0)$
For the point like $(x,0)$ i used $y=x$ and $y=-x$.
From the first I got $\Delta f(x,x)=x^5$ so $\Delta f\geq 0$ when $x\geq0$  and $\Delta f< 0$ when $x<0$.
Using the other curve $y=-x$ I got the opposite results so that I can state that $(x,0)$ are point of sadle.
**It is right? Is there a easier way to prove that?**

Anyway this method doesn't help me evaluating the point in the form $(0,y)$. I mean that I got $\Delta f=y^5$ with both the curves.

I also thought that if I consider $x\rightarrow 0$ with Y held constant $f(x,y)=x^2y^3$ is 
$f\geq 0$ when $y\geq0$ and the point are minimum other way when $y<0$ also $f<0$ so the point are maximum.
But in a sort of way it seems not that rigorous to me.
**Any suggestion?**

Comment: Yes that's more or less what I've noticed in the last part. If $y$ is held constant I have parabolas (whose concavity change on the values of the constant and the point is max or min according to it) otherways if $x$ is held constant the curve is cubics which has a inflection no matter the values of x. But is this rigorous? My doubt was if there's a more specific way, like a method or something like that. Probably I'm just unsatisfied but it actually works.

Comment: I think the graph helps to show that the critical points on the axes are different in  character from each other. Second derivative is a point of inflection , first derivative a point of local maxima or minima.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I believe this drawing gives a good idea of the situation. The Parabolas cut by the y- axis have extrema on the y- axis . The Cubics cut by the x- axis have points of inflection along the the x - axis.

In the drawing x=1 (in cyan) , y = 1 (in pink).

Comment: Yes I think this could help, so basically my idea was right and the conclusion I draw are correct isn't it?
I mean they could be considered a right approach to the problem.

Comment: Yes, I think you're fine. The only thing is, it helps to look at the thing, (for me) if possible. There an easy characterization  in this case, and it can be illustrated with a drawing . I assume you will need your analysis too.

Comment: Yes, since I was not provided any solutions or hint for the problem I was asking for a confirmation and may be something giving me another perspective of the problem leading to the same conclusion; and the drawing works properly. Thanks.